# I have a HP Pavilion laptop. It will boot Ubuntu but not a windows 10 ISO. Whats wrong?

Tags: boot, usb, iso-image

I have a Ubuntu and a windows 10 ISO on my machine.

I have used Rufus to create a bootable USB drive first from the Ubuntu ISO, and this works. When I do the same from my windows 10 ISO it does not. Is there any special things I need to do to make this boot windows?

I have tried burning the windows ISO to disk, and it still will not boot from the optical drive. Has anyone had similar experiences?

Plugging the USB in to my main machine it will boot from it just fine. I'm at a wits end as to what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Go in to the BIOS settings and enable legacy boot mode.
The windows 10 bootable USB will then boot as normal.

*This problem plagued me for like a week and i still dont really understand why this happened*